# 'str' object has no attribute 'tk' - AttributeError

Tags: python, tkinter, attributes

This is my code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter.constants import *

import random as r



def Game():
    a = r.randint(1, 100)
    b = tk.Entry(width=25)
    if b == int(a):
        l1 = tk.Label("correct, the number was", int(a))
        l1.grid(column = 0, row = 0)
    elif b != a:
        l2 = tk.Label("wrong, the number was", int(a))
        l2.grid(column = 0, row = 0)

window = tk.Tk()
window.title("Guess the number game")
window.geometry("300x400+10+20")
btn=tk.Button(window, text="Start game", fg='blue', bg = 'green')
btn.grid(column=1000,row=1)
window.bind("<Button-1>",lambda event:Game())
label_name = tk.Label(text ="Guess the Number Game", font=("Times new roman",20))
label_name.grid(column=1000,row=0)
window.mainloop()
```

I want to make a number guessing game, but it's just giving the same error and I don't know what it means when the error says:

> AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'tk'

Comment: Can you post the full traceback? You haven't posted anything that uses the attribute `tk`

Comment: you are overriding some variable and calling something like `var.tk` somewhere. Do a ctrl+f search on your code for `.tk` and find where it's called. Then, look for where you overwrite the name that just preceeds the `.tk`.

Comment: You can't use a string as the parent for a widget. `tk.Label("correct, ...")` tells `Label` to be  a child of that string.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter.constants import *

import random as r

window = tk.Tk()

def Game():
    a = r.randint(1, 100)
    b = tk.Entry(width=25)
    if b == int(a):
        l1 = tk.Label(window, text="correct, the number was {0}".format(a))
        l1.grid(column = 1000, row = 2)
    elif b != a:
        l2 = tk.Label(window, text="wrong, the number was  {0}".format(a))
        l2.grid(column = 1000, row = 2)


window.title("Guess the number game")
window.geometry("300x400+10+20")
btn=tk.Button(window, text="Start game", command=Game,fg='blue', bg = 'green')
btn.grid(column=1000,row=1)
#window.bind("<Button-1>",lambda event:Game())
label_name = tk.Label(text ="Guess the Number Game", font=("Times new roman",20))
label_name.grid(column=1000,row=0)
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: bro your code worked. but how? i don't get it

Comment: I replace this  tk.Label("correct, to tk.Label(window,